# How did minor 2nd get its name?

Tags: theory, scales, intervals

In the natural, or harmonic or melodic minor scale, we do not find the minor 2nd note which is rather found in Phrygian or Locrian Mode, or maybe Ionian#1. Then why is this note called minor 2nd if it does not find a place in minor scale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intervals of a second, third, sixth, seventh, ninth and so on come in pairs: *smaller* and *larger*. The larger *n*-th is always one semitone larger than the smaller one. Smaller second - one semitone, larger second - two semitones. Smaller third - three semitones, larger third - four semitones.

For some reason, English uses words borrowed from Latin for this distinction.

The Latin word for "larger" is **major**.
The Latin word for "smaller" is **minor**.

The minor second is literally **the smaller second**.

The interval isn't named after the scale; the scale is named after an interval. Namely, the third.

The major and minor scales are shorthand for "the scale with the major/minor third in it". (If you get into the various minor scales, you can notice that the harmonic minor scale has a major seventh, and the melodic minor scale also has a major sixth, but the minor third is what makes them minor scales by definition.)

Comment: yes, that third thing, I kinda knew, and that's why ionian, lydian, mixolydian is major while dorian, phrygian, aeolian and locrian are minor. But then why is not the tritone named like that, minor 5th, why is it named perfect?

Comment: @SarbanBhattacharya The tritone is the *diminished* fifth, or augmented fourth. The fifth and fourth (and octave and prime) are called "perfect" because they don't come in major and minor variant but only one. But how all that came to be is something I know too little about to answer. I only have this vague notion that it must have something to do with the fact that they're the simplest-ratio intervals.

Comment: @Laurence Really, augmented for the second but not for the [unison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_unison), or [fourth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tritone#Augmented_fourth_and_diminished_fifth), or [fifth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_fifth), or [octave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_octave)? And also for some reason once augmented or diminished intervals count but doubly diminished or doubly augmented (or [more](https://sites.google.com/view/musicalharmonysite/part-i-general-music-theory/intervals/multiply-diminished-and-augmented-intervals)) don't?

Comment: Deeply sorry about the unforgivable simplification there. Truth is, any perfect or major interval can be augmented an unlimited number of times, and any perfect or minor interval can be diminished at least as long as you don't get into a negative interval size, at which point it becomes disputable (but some people don't mind allowing even things like a triply diminished second between Gx and Abb).

Comment: Now, that was not simplified, but also not very useful. Let's get back to the idea that the baseline quality of an interval is either perfect, or comes in a pair of major or minor. And then from there, it can be augmented or diminished - once or even doubly, triply and so on.

Comment: @Divizna Yes you're right, there are THREE basic flavours of unison, 4th, 5th and octave, not just two..  And that's before we start inventing doubly augmented or diminished intervals.

Comment: @Laurence - like to delete your earlier comment, which didn't include augmenteds?

Answer (score 1):

The term minor in these cases refers to smaller (major = greater/larger). So a m2 is smaller as an interval than M2, by one semitone.

It has nothing at all to do with notes in the minor key. Even though a lot of major intervals are found in major keys.

Comment: @sarbanbhattacharya To avoid confusion, when we talk about notes in a scale being higher or lower, we use words like "flat/sharp" or "raised/lowered." And this usually means these scale degrees have been changed from "normal," maybe from whatever the scale usually uses.